# Entering Russia via land border as a UK/Israeli citizen

Tags: covid-19, borders

I would like to travel from Riga to Moscow by bus, is it possible? There are buses available but can I enter as a UK/Israeli citizen?

I believe they lifted the ban for air travel but not for the land one. do you know if its still in force?

Comment: NB: Many western countries currently warn against non-essential travel to Russia.  Check with your country's foreign affairs office and consider what impact ignoring a travel warning may have on travel insurance.

Comment: @gerrit that is of course very sound advice, but I would point out that in this case it should read "check with your countries' foreign affairs offices," since there are two of them.  For example, the diplomatic situation with one country could be significantly different from that with the other one.

Comment: @phoog True.  Which reminds me: if abducted by terrorists (extreme example), having two passports doesn't hurt (a [camouflage passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camouflage_passport) may even save lives, but is unlikely to convince Russian police).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Israeli passport should allow visa-free entry into Russia. The war in Ukraine strained relations between the two countries but not to the level of denying entry.

Israel currently has not travel warnings regarding Russia ([Hebrew source](https://www.gov.il/he/Departments/DynamicCollectors/travel-warnings?skip=0&continent=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%94&country=%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%94)), except for specific ones for Chechnia and crossing into Georgia. Regarding covid-19, the same site says travel is "allowed but not recommended" - same as most world countries.

A significant challenge may be getting money while in Russia. I believe most non-Russian credit card will not work, so check your options with care.

Comment: hello and thank you for answering. im specifically concerned whether the travel ban by land is still in force (from 2020 because of covid). I believe they lifted the ban for air travel but not for the land one. do you know if its still in force?

Comment: Are you sure?  If Russia requires travel insurance, but Israel warns against non-essential travel to Russia, then that travel warning may invalidate the travel insurance and thus the condition for travelling to Russia is not met?  Just wondering.

Comment: @user, don't know about aban for land travel, but you wrote yourself that buses are available.

Comment: @gerrit, Updated answer, no such warning. Also I don't know if insurance purchased outside of Israel would be invalidated due to Israeli warnings.

Comment: @gerrit, ugoren: whether any travel insurance would be invalidated by any warning depends on the policy language.  An insurer in any country could for example include a clause conditioning coverage on the absence of travel warnings from the traveler's country of citizenship (I have no idea whether such clauses are in fact used).  One might have to look at all countries of citizenship or perhaps only at the one whose passport is being used.  But, ugoren, it seems a serious omission in this answer not to discuss UK travel advice.  If one country allows its citizens to travel somewhere, that...

Comment: ... doesn't mean that it's a good idea to go.  The other country could be warning its citizens against travel there because of political risks that don't apply to citizens of the first country -- but this person could still be exposed to those risks.  For example, if the US and Canada were at war, Mexico might not advise against Mexicans traveling to the US, but a dual citizen of Mexico and Canada would be an enemy alien in the US regardless of the passport used to enter.

Comment: Non-Russian-bank issued Visa/MasterCard JCB will NOT work. UnionPay will very likely work ATMs but it's acceptance is...limited. Check if you can get MIR card while in Israel.  possible alternative is QIWI virtual card (only Russian phone number is necessary, card will have limits) + crypto currency (it could be done with sites like bestchange.ru but it's not officially allowed).